# (AndroidX) Unable to build "AMM0000" - Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

When building a Xamarin Android project we sporadically get these exceptions. Any ideas how to remove the flakiness? looks like an Xamarin Android bug?

[image: 4]

Steps to Reproduce

1. Install Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources
2. Build
3. See warnings

Expected Behavior

No errors

Actual Behavior

Environment

```
=== Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.7.8 (build 4)
Installation UUID: 6c568fc0-cf38-440a-8b1a-594e0e92e9ac
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)

    Package version: 612000093

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
    Mono 6.12.0.93 (2020-02/620cf538206) (64-bit)
    Package version: 612000093

=== Roslyn (Language Service) ===

3.7.0-6.20427.1+18ede13943b0bfae1b44ef078b2f3923159bcd32

=== NuGet ===

Version: 5.7.0.6702

=== .NET Core SDK ===

SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    3.1.402
    3.1.302
    3.1.200
    3.1.102
    3.1.101
    3.1.100
    3.0.100
    2.1.504
    2.1.302
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

=== .NET Core Runtime ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    3.1.8
    3.1.6
    3.1.2
    3.1.1
    3.1.0
    3.0.0
    2.1.22
    2.1.20
    2.1.17
    2.1.15
    2.1.14
    2.1.13
    2.1.8
    2.1.2

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.12.29
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Updater ===

Version: 11

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 12.0.1 (17220)
Build 12A7300

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 11.0.2.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-7/025fde9
Android SDK: /Users/curauser/Library/Android/sdk
    Supported Android versions:
        4.4 (API level 19)
        5.0 (API level 21)
        6.0 (API level 23)
        8.0 (API level 26)
        8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 29.0.6
SDK Build Tools Version: 28.0.3

Build Information: 
Mono: 83105ba
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-7@1f3388a
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/proguard6.2.2@ebe9000
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.32.1@1a3276b
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-7@017078f

=== Microsoft OpenJDK for Mobile ===

Java SDK: /Users/curauser/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Android SDK Manager ===

Version: 16.7.0.13
Hash: 8380518
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-7~2
Build date: 2020-09-16 05:12:24 UTC

=== Android Device Manager ===

Version: 16.7.0.24
Hash: bb090a3
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-7
Build date: 2020-09-16 05:12:46 UTC

=== Xamarin Designer ===

Version: 16.7.0.495
Hash: 03d50a221
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-7-vsmac
Build date: 2020-08-28 13:12:52 UTC

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 14.0.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 7ec3751a1
Branch: xcode12
Build date: 2020-09-16 11:33:15-0400

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 807080004
Git revision: 9ea7bef96d65cdc3f4288014a799026ccb1993bc
Build date: 2020-09-16 17:22:54-04
Build branch: release-8.7
Xamarin extensions: 9ea7bef96d65cdc3f4288014a799026ccb1993bc

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.15.6
Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0
    Thu Jun 18 20:49:00 PDT 2020
    root:xnu-6153.141.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

#### Build Logs

https://gist.github.com/moerabaya/c1cc8fdbb124c17028f82e11adf7595f

#### Example Project (If Possible)

#### Packages

1-
[image: 1]

2-
[image: 2]

3-
[image: 3]

Comment: We are having this issue as well .. anyone can help ?

Comment: Have you try to migrate "packages.config" to "PackageReferences"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

Comment: Yes we already migrated and yet we have the same issue. @WendyZang-MSFT

Comment: Please check the sample in the link below. https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/72 It thrown the same error as yours and now it has been fixed. I hope this would be helpful.